# synonyms containing multiple words

Tags: java, solr, lucene, search-engine

I am using solr as a search engine.

I would like to map some words or phrases to something else, Example:

```
Drama and Theatre Studies=>drama
```

Using the synonyms hasn't worked for me unless it is a single word.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: did you check the synonym file format at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory

Comment: I did check the file, it says "Keep in mind that while the SynonymFilter will happily work with synonyms containing multiple words"

Answer (score 0):

Your terms and phrase terms in the synonim file should be separed by comma.

Maybe the mapping of phrases is not working because of lower-case/upper-case difference. Check the order of `solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory` and `solr.SynonymFilterFactory`. 
Given your synonym file is all lower case, you should set `LowerCaseFilterFactory` first and then `SynonymFilterFactory`.